# Expanding $(x+yi)^c$ to series

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, power-series, laurent-series

I need to evaluate a complex expression $f(x,y)=(x+yi)^c$, where $x,y,c\in\mathbb{R}$, in double-precision arithmetic on the GPU.

It is done in a usual way, i.e., computing  $\exp(c \log(x + yi))$. Eventually, it boils
down to evaluating such functions like: $\exp$, $\log$, $\arctan$, $\sqrt{x}$, $\sin$ and $\cos$. Since GPU anyway has very limited support for transcendental math, these functions are evaluated using some sort of power series in double-precision arithmetic (which is quite expensive).

My question is: is there any way to compute $f(x,y)$ more efficiently ?
I.e., expanding it into some power series for variables $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Do you need the complex result or just the real or imaginary part ?

Comment: yes, just real and imaginary parts

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995355/can-anyone-help-me-to-find-the-result-of-abin-by-three-methods-when-n-is

Comment: @Nilan, thanks for the link, perhaps I can get some ideas, but in my case $c\in\mathbb{R}$, not integer

Answer (score 1):

How about trying;

\begin{eqnarray}
(x+yi)^{c} &=& \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \binom{c}{m}x^{c-m}(yi)^{m} \\
           &=& \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \binom{c}{m}x^{c-m}y^{m}i^{m} \\
           &=& \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \binom{c}{m}x^{c-m}y^{m} e^{i m \pi/2}
\end{eqnarray}

And proceeding from there?

Comment: What's $n$? (Shouldn't it be $\infty$? If $c$ is an integer, the terms are eventually $0$. If not, it turns into an infinite series, which it should be.)

Comment: ops, sorry for confusion, but $c\in\mathbb{R}$, so this will not work. I'll fix the question

Comment: Since we're talking about finite representations of numbers (double-precision floating points), you would never take an infinite sum. At the very most, you would take that sum to $n$ where it is no different from $n + 1$.

Comment: Ah! Added edit to show sum to infinity, but I now see that $c$ is complex so my idea is junk.

Comment: Your idea isn't junk. Just separate $c$ into an integer $\lfloor c\rfloor$ and a real $c - \lfloor c\rfloor$.

Comment: That way, it turns into $f(x, y) = (x + yi)^{\lfloor c \rfloor}(x + yi)^{c - \lfloor c \rfloor}$.

Comment: But I am confused: one still needs to evaluate $(x+yi)^{c-\lfloor c \rfloor}$ even if ${c-\lfloor c \rfloor}$ is just a fraction

Comment: @asm Do you know the Generalized Binomial Theorem? It's like the binomial theorem, but works when the exponent isn't an integer.

Comment: huh you are right, Binomial Coeffs can be computed even if $c$ is not an integer.. I need to play around with this in maple, thanks